# Passing an instance method (of a struct) to ThreadStart seems to update a spurious instance as the original is unaffected

Tags: c#, multithreading, methods, struct, locking

My problem is passing the `this.folderFolder` instance method to `ThreadStart` ctor. I step through it with `dirAssThread` and watch it update the instance data member correctly and complete, then I trap back to

```
if (dirAssThread.IsAlive) completeThread(-1); //***ie abort
```

and find that the data member of the same `this` instance that I passed with the method to the `ThreadStart` ctor has miraculously reset itself to 0!

Here are the other functions

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace MonitorService
{
    struct myStruct
    {
        long bytesSzMember;
        Thread dirAssThread;
        private Object thisLock;

        private void completeThread(long bytesSzNew)
        {
            lock (thisLock)
            {
                if (bytesSzNew == -1)
                {
                    dirAssThread.Abort();
                    Console.WriteLine("A thread timed out.");
                }
                else
                {
                    bytesSzMember = bytesSzNew;
                    Console.WriteLine("A thread update size.");
                }
            }
        }

        private void folderFolder()
        {
            long bytesSzNew = 0;
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\SomeDir");
            DirectoryInfo[] directories = di.GetDirectories("*",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                bytesSzNew += file.Length;
            }
            completeThread(bytesSzNew);
        }

        private void updateSize()
        {
            thisLock = new Object();
            dirAssThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.folderFolder));
            dirAssThread.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            if (dirAssThread.IsAlive) completeThread(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what your code is doing - can you post more information, or ideally a short but complete program?

Comment: @Henrik, no to ensure integrity its proposed update is forwarded to completeThread to ensure it is not due for and being terminated before the update occurs.

Comment: @Henrik, out of the 3 I would have to suppose I mean, bytesSzCode

Comment: @chibacity, It _will_ finish, 5000ms is adequate time to add the sizes. And it will update the size. If it has not finished it will be preempted and bytesSzNew will not get copied to byteSzCode.

Comment: @chibacity I know it will pass -1 if and when it _cannot_ have finished. The effect will be to preempt that thread. This is a watchdog terminator to prevent circular references in the searched directory structure.

Comment: @chibacity, ahhhh. I know. It has been set by a previous call and will be used to compute the difference in file sizes. The 0 value would never get applied unless it was otherwise obtained as the sum measurement of all the files.

Comment: @John I have supplied some alternative code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

After the question title update, the problem you are seeing is that structs are copied on reference. You are passing a copy of your struct when assigning the delegate to the thread, and it is this copy that will be updated by the thread. When you do your check in `completeThread` it is against the original which has not been updated.

Use a class instead of a struct.

**Alternate Solution**

I would suggest using wait handles instead of sleeps and thread aborts, as `Thread.Abort` is considered a dangerous practice and should be avoided (quite easily in this case). I propose the following solution which is a recursive version that will not follow circular references (so there is no need to abort in reality, the code can be removed if you do not want a timeout facility).

```
public class WaitForFileSizes
{
    private readonly object _syncObj = new object();
    private readonly HashSet<string> _seenDirectories = new HashSet<string>();
    private readonly ManualResetEvent _pEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private long _totalFileSize;
    private Thread _thread;
    private volatile bool _abort;

    private void UpdateSize()
    {
        _thread = new Thread(GetDirectoryFileSize);
        _thread.Start();

        bool timedout = !_pEvent.WaitOne(5000);

        if (timedout)
        {
            _abort = true;
            _pEvent.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine("A thread timed out.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Total size {0}b.", _totalFileSize);
        }
    }

    private void GetDirectoryFileSize()
    {
        GetDirectoryFileSizesRecursively(new DirectoryInfo("C:\\temp"));

        _pEvent.Set();
    }

    private void GetDirectoryFileSizesRecursively(DirectoryInfo dir)
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(dir.EnumerateFiles(), f =>
        {
            if (_abort)
            {
                _pEvent.Set();
                return;
            }

            Interlocked.Add(ref _totalFileSize, f.Length);
        });

        Parallel.ForEach(dir.EnumerateDirectories(), d =>
        {
            if (!IsSeen(d))
            {
                GetDirectoryFileSizesRecursively(d);
            }
        });
    }

    private bool IsSeen(DirectoryInfo dir)
    {
        lock (_syncObj)
        {
            if (!_seenDirectories.Contains(dir.FullName))
            {
                _seenDirectories.Add(dir.FullName);

                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

As we now have circular reference detection, the threading and abort code can be removed as that was previously there to abort the thread if it was in an endless loop - no need for that now:

```
public class WaitForFileSizes
{
    private readonly object _syncObj = new object();
    private readonly HashSet<string> _seenDirectories = new HashSet<string>();
    private long _t;

    public void UpdateSize()
    {
        GetSize(new DirectoryInfo("C:\\temp"));

        Console.WriteLine("Total size {0}b.", _t);
    }

    private void GetSize(DirectoryInfo dir)
    {
        Parallel
        .ForEach(dir.EnumerateFiles(), f => Interlocked.Add(ref _t, f.Length));

        Parallel
        .ForEach(dir.EnumerateDirectories().Where(IsNewDir), GetSize);
    }

    private bool IsNewDir(FileSystemInfo dir)
    {
        lock (_syncObj)
        {
            if (!_seenDirectories.Contains(dir.FullName))
            {
                _seenDirectories.Add(dir.FullName);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I need some way to preempt the thread so that that di.GetDirectories call doesn't hang on circular (sym link) references. That was the whole point of my using a thread.

Comment: @John Are you saying that if you have a circular reference that this hangs before you get to the foreach loop?

Comment: Yes, that is in the contract for di.GetDirectories

Comment: @John You could consider using recursion then instead of `SearchOption.AllDirectories`. You will then be able to exit your loop, and could also handle circular reference detection if you so wished.

Comment: recursion is noughties I need more exposure to c# and parrallelism. I see the 2 solutions are of comparable elegance now. Gonna try using class instead of struct.

Comment: I'm not certain but I think there is a problem with this when using structs instead of classes (unlike C++). The problem has now vanished.

Comment: @John I have added an implementation that includes a recursive algorithm.

Comment: @John Oh dear, I missed that completely. There are quite a few gotchas when using structs in .Net. You should generally use classes, plenty of stuff on this site covers this. Anyway, the above will allow you to do what you need to do following some best practice i.e. not using `Thread.Abort` and using appropriate thread synchronization. `Thread.Abort` is evil...

Comment: @John Updated my answer in response to you question title update.

Comment: @John I have updated the version to include circular reference detection, so even directories with circular references in can be accurately measured. No need for abort.

Comment: damn that's elegant. Not sure I know enough about hashmaps but I deffo see the advantage of a collection here. Thanks for your parrallel development.

Comment: @John The HashSet is a collection of unique items, which has quick lookup time to see if an item is already added. We can use this sort of collection to track if we have already seen a directory which will occur when there is a circular reference. If we do detect that a directory has been seen, then we stop following that branch - we've already done it. If you remove the timeout code, it's quite elegant :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are having here is that you are passing a method of a `struct` to the `ThreadStart` constructor and that causes it to make a copy of the `struct` instance and invoke the method on the copy. Your code is running, but it is updating the copy not the original instance.

Try changing the `struct` to `class` and you should see the problem go away.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the nuances of value (struct) types. There are very few reasons to use a value type - and in a wide variety of cases they add overhead (instead of eliminating it, like you would assume).

Just change the type declaration to `class`. Furthermore, if you want a timeout for this function, why not try the following (you can eliminate the class altogether):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CalculateSize("C:\\", 1000,
            result => Console.WriteLine("Finished: {0} bytes", result),
            (result, ex) => Console.WriteLine("Incomplete results: {0} bytes - {1}", result, ex.Message));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void CalculateSize(string directory, int timeout, Action<long> onSuccess, Action<long, Exception> onFailure)
    {
        // Create an invoke a delegate on a separate thread.
        var del = new Action<string, int, Action<long>, Action<long, Exception>>(CalculateSizeImpl);
        del.BeginInvoke(directory, timeout, onSuccess, onFailure, iar =>
            {
                try
                {
                    del.EndInvoke(iar);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    onFailure(0, ex);
                }
            }, null);
    }

    static void CalculateSizeImpl(string directory, int timeout, Action<long> onSuccess, Action<long, Exception> onFailure)
    {
        var completeBy = Environment.TickCount + timeout;
        var size = 0L;
        var visited = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        try
        {
            CalculateSizeRecursive(directory, completeBy, ref size, visited);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Call the failure callback, but give the
            // value before the timeout to it.
            onFailure(size, ex);
            return;
        }
        // Just return the value.
        onSuccess(size);
    }

    static void CalculateSizeRecursive(string directory, int completeBy, ref long size, HashSet<string> visited)
    {
        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*"))
        {
            if (Environment.TickCount > completeBy)
                throw new TimeoutException();
            size += new FileInfo(file).Length;
        }

        // Cannot use SearchOption.All, because you won't get incomplete results -
        // only ever 0 or the actual value.
        foreach (var dir in Directory.GetDirectories(directory, "*"))
        {
            if (Environment.TickCount > completeBy)
                throw new TimeoutException();
            if (visited.Add(dir))
                CalculateSizeRecursive(dir, completeBy, ref size, visited);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's a lot to get my head around :)